# How can I configure MATLAB so that upon a Ctrl+C fclose('all') get called?

Tags: matlab

I would like to have `fclose('all')` get called whenever I force the script/function to exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I know that for a given function I can add [`finishup = onCleanup(@() fclose('all'));`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html) at the beginning. However, it is tedious to do it for each function, and doesn't seem to me very neat. How can I configure MATLAB so that upon a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> fclose('all') get called?

The motivation is to avoid this kind of messages after I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> some code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go here is changing your workflow a bit. Here is what I recommend:

```
try
% open, process and close file
catch
% close file
end
```

Assuming you have not abused `try catch` to guide your process flow you can now simply debug with `dbstop if caught error`, perhaps whilst mentioning the error. Now you can still interrupt the code with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and afterwards just let the code continue to close the file.

You can think of other solutions as well, like forcing all files to be closed, just before you require them all to be closed, but then you may need to worry about closing too many files.